# Can Lombok's @RequiredArgsConstructor initialize a Spring-Webflux WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, lombok

I have a controller class with a `private final WebClient webClient`.
While the rest of the private final fields can be initialized with the @RequiredArgsConstructor provided by Lombok. A Spring-Webflux WebClient object seems to only be able to be initialized like this: `this.webClient = WebClientBuilder.build()` and thus the lombok generated constructor doesn't work.
Is there a way around this?

Sample code:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class SomeController {
  private final SomeService someService;

  private final SomeConfig someConfig;

  private final SomeOtherConfig someOtherConfig;

  private final WebClient webClient;

  // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not because of Lombok. Spring injects dependencies when they exist within the application context. Spring will create instances only when they are annotated with Spring stereotypes or are created via `@Bean` annotation or are part of Auto-Configuration. The `Webclient` instance needs to exist within the application context to be injected.

To inject `WebClient` you can create the same as below in your configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(){
        return WebClient.builder().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! I should have guessed the issue would arise from my misunderstanding of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

for me, previous response wasn't working, but is base for my response.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder){
        return webClientBuilder.build();
    }
}
```